# iText 7 Embedded files on append mode does not work

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(
        new PdfReader(in),
        new PdfWriter(destPath),
        new StampingProperties().useAppendMode());

PdfFileSpec spec = PdfFileSpec.createEmbeddedFileSpec(
        pdfDoc,
        annex.getInputStream(),
        annex.getFileName(),
        annex.getFileName(),
        null, null, null);

pdfDoc.addFileAttachment(annex.getFileName(), spec);
log.info("add file attachment:{}", annex.getFileName());

pdfDoc.close();
```

Comment: Please clarify what "does not work". In my tests, adding an embedded file works correctly, both with and without _append mode_. Tested with the latest version (7.1.15).

Answer (score 2):

With this code and iText 7.1.15, I have tested adding an embedded file, with and without *append mode*.

```java
String fileName = "test.txt";

StampingProperties stampingProp = new StampingProperties();
if (append)
    stampingProp.useAppendMode();

PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(in), new PdfWriter(dest),
        stampingProp);
PdfFileSpec spec = PdfFileSpec.createEmbeddedFileSpec(pdfDoc, new FileInputStream(fileName),
        fileName, fileName, null, null, null);
pdfDoc.addFileAttachment(fileName, spec);
pdfDoc.close();
```

In both cases, the file is embedded correctly, and it shows up as expected when opening the resulting PDF documents in a PDF viewer.

Diffs of the input and outputs PDF, just to verify the first one was updated with *append mode*, and the second one without:

[image: diff 1]

[image: diff 2]